# Routing error for "show" action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Good day, there are a lot of questions on this problem here, but they don't help me.

For `signed_in` user I have a homepage with `bookmarks` and `folders`, which contains bookmarks belonged to this folder.

`home` method is in `static_pages` controller, which looks like this:

```
def home
    if signed_in?
      @folder = current_user.folders.build
      @folders = current_user.folders.all
      @bookmark = current_user.bookmarks.build
      @bookmarks = current_user.bookmarks.all
    end
  end
```

This is part of `home.html.erb`

```
<div class="span3">
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
          <%= render @bookmarks %>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="span3">
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
          <%= render @folders %>
        </table>
      </div>
```

So I have 2 tables with all `bookmarks` and all `folders`, belonged to `current_user`

This is `_folder.html.erb` from `folders` folder in `views`

```
<tr data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-html="true">
  <td data-href="<%= folder %>" class="bookmark"><i class="icon-folder-close"></i>
    <%= link_to folder.name, folder_path %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to '<i class="icon-edit"></i>'.html_safe, '#' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to '<i class="icon-trash"></i>'.html_safe, folder_path, method: :delete,
                data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'},
                title: 'Delete folder ' + folder.name.to_s %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

`folders_controller.rb`, with `show` method:

```
def show
    @folder = Folder.find(params[:id])
    @bookmarks = @folder.bookmarks.all
  end
```

also `resources :folders` exists `routes.rb`

All I need is to go to `localhost:3000/folder/1`, when clicking on `folder_name` on homepage.

This is what I get:

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"folders"}
```

In `rake routes` everything is ok.

When put `localhost:3000/folder/1` in browser, it works correctly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Replacing:

```
 <%= link_to folder.name, folder_path %>
```

with

```
 <%= link_to folder.name, folder_path(folder) %>
```

as you need to provide the id to the show action.

You can get more information [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't help me. Now, when clicking on `folder_name`, I see this in address bar: `http://localhost:3000/#<Folder:0x007fa25b685f38>`, but it still doesn't visit `folder/1`.

Comment: try `folder_path(folder.id)` or `folder_path(:id => folder.id)`